# View detailed MetaData on old DOS files

Tags: file-metadata

I'm trying to get detailed information on how to view metadata of files recovered from a faulty drive, on Linux Mint 18.  The files are from an old computer running Windows 2000 and DOS.

I've tried checking for this information by right-clicking the file, and selecting properties, but there is only limited information.  Specifically, trying to figure out:

- What program generated these files.
- When they were created.
- When they were last accessed.

I've done various Google searches, but get results on how to remove metadata, or view/edit metadata for images/music.  Most of these files are `PGM`, `DAT`, `IDX`, `BAT`, or other, old file types.

Comment: Are you sure in that informations are stored on FAT16?

Comment: I was looking into this, and found that FAT16 does store some metadata.  However, I realized that I forgot to mention that this data was recovered from a faulty drive.

Comment: The metadata you are trying to find is not recorded within the FAT16 filesystem itself.  Unclear where you are hoping to find it. See http://www.maverick-os.dk/FileSystemFormats/FAT16_FileSystem.html

Comment: @steve Yes, FAT16 doesn't store much, but the computer that ran the recovery utility would.  I'm just trying to get any data on these files that I can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did some digging, and found that this question is actually answered on [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/355360/how-to-display-file-properties-via-terminal):

```
user@computer $ stat SET_IO.PGM
 File: 'SET_IO.PGM'
Size: 616           Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 801h/2049d  Inode: 23724477    Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: ( 1000/    user)   Gid: ( 1000/    user)
Access: 2016-11-15 11:45:40.701739090 -0600
Modify: 1987-03-08 01:02:46.000000000 -0600
Change: 2016-11-15 11:44:37.099127157 -0600
Birth: -
```